# 360 game controller Linux device driver issue calling my probe function

Tags: c++, c, linux, driver, device

I am trying to learn USB Linux device driver. I picked MS XBOX 360 controller. I noticed there is a generic driver (xpad.ko) for Linux. Needless to say, my code is based on xpad.c. Anyways, I built my driver (360.ko). modprobe -r on current driver (xpad, led_class, even usbhid). also blacklisted xpad driver. Did insmod on my driver (360.ko). USBcore registers my driver (usbcore: registered new interface driver Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller). However, it does not invoke my usb_360_probe() . Any clues?????

```
static struct usb_driver uDriver = {
     .name =         "Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller",
     .probe =        usb_360_probe,
     .disconnect =   usb_360_disconnect,
     .id_table =     skel_table,

};

#define USB_360_VENDOR_ID 0x045E
#define USB_360_PRODUCT_ID 0x0202//0x0289//0x028E //I tried all these product IDs!

static struct usb_device_id skel_table[] = {
 { USB_DEVICE(USB_360_VENDOR_ID, USB_360_PRODUCT_ID) },
 {},
 };

static int usb_360_probe(struct usb_interface *intf, const struct usb_device_id*id)
{
printk(KERN_INFO, "(360)usb_360_probe.\n");

}

static int __init usb_360_init(void)
{
int result;

printk(KERN_INFO, "(360)usb_360_init.\n");

/* register this driver with the USB subsystem */
 result = usb_register(&uDriver);
 if (result)
 {
    printk(KERN_INFO, "(360)usb_register failed.\n");
 }

  printk(KERN_INFO, "(360)usb_register succeeded.\n");

 return result;
 }

static void __exit usb_360_exit(void)
{


/* deregister this driver with the USB subsystem */
usb_deregister(&uDriver);
printk(KERN_INFO, "(360)usb_unregister succeeded.\n");
}

module_init(usb_360_init);
module_exit(usb_360_exit);
```

//I am using printk(KERN_INFO) to for the dmesg message. It works for my other char drivers.

kernel: 2.6.32-21-generic

Answer (score 1):

Your probe function will be called when a device inserted with the given vendor id product id is found. Do you have the said device? Is it inserted?.

Comment: Of course device is inserted. dmesg shows: (360)usb_360_init. usbcore: registered new interface driver Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller. (36)usb_register succeeded.  but no probe() call!!! also, dmesg shows: usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 5. usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you initiate cdev struct? From my experience I basically just make a cdev struct and then tell the kernel about it. Your file_operations structure is responsible for calling the function. I don't see any of those structures in your driver program. Now I'm pretty new at writting drivers, but I know that all drivers need to initiate a cdev struct, file_operation struct, and open file struct to do anything. One book that helps me a lot is a free pdf that you can google linux device drivers 3rd edition. Maybe this helps. Good luck.

Comment: probe is usually comes before open, close and other file operations. Also, I do not need user application to make a system call to open, close etc. Inside probe, it uses USB - interrupt to catch event such as button press etc. That code goes inside probe, I have all the code stubbed out. My issue is probe() is not calling.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the solution. vedasolutions was right. Product Id was wrong. probe() is called as soon as I changed the product id. Also, I have to raise level of logging to see my message. For simplicity I just took out KERN_INFO in printk, that logs all the messages in dmesg. Thanks anyways.

However I have another issue :(. Now my probe is being called multiple times. 4 times and results in null pointer exception.  It seems like probe failed so it is retrying to probe again. 
Here is the log of dmesg ---->

```
(360)usb_360_init.
[410803.812983] usbcore: registered new interface driver Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller
[410803.813017] (360)usb_register succeeded.
[410816.146730] usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 9
[410816.318924] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[410816.332264] (360)usb_360_probe.
[410816.332281] (360)usb_360_probe device found!!.
[input: 360 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.0/input/input4
[410816.372435] (360)probe succeeded.
[410816.372509] Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller: probe of 2-1:1.0 failed with error 1
[410816.372624] (360)usb_360_probe.
[410816.372626] (360)usb_360_probe device found!!.
input: 360 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-1/2- 1:1.1/input/input5
[410816.372739] (360)probe succeeded.
[410816.372748] Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller: probe of 2-1:1.1 failed with error 1
[410816.374083] (360)usb_360_probe.
[410816.374088] (360)usb_360_probe device found!!.
input: 360 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.2/input/input6
[410816.374852] (360)probe succeeded.
[410816.374871] Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller: probe of 2-1:1.2 failed with error 1
[410816.378827] (360)usb_360_probe.
[410816.379168] (360)usb_360_probe device found!!.
[410816.380925] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 00000006
[410816.380967] IP: [<f84ae438>] usb_360_probe+0x1a8/0x318 [360]
[410816.381485] *pde = bf838067 
[410816.381601] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[410816.381643] last sysfs file:        [410816.382272] Pid: 44, comm: khubd Not tainted     

(2.6.32-21-generic #32-Ubuntu) VMware Virtual Platform
```

lsusb -v shows:

/*
   Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller

Device Descriptor:
   bLength                18
   bDescriptorType         1
   bcdUSB               2.00
   bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
   bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
   bDeviceProtocol       255 Vendor Specific Protocol
   bMaxPacketSize0         8
   idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
   idProduct          0x028e Xbox360 Controller
   bcdDevice            1.14
   iManufacturer           1 
   iProduct                2 
   iSerial                 3 
   bNumConfigurations      1
   Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          153
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass     93 
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              0 
      ** UNRECOGNIZED:  11 21 00 01 01 25 81 14 00 00 00 00 13 01 08 00 00 **(PROBLEM??????!!!)**
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               4
    */